# Tableau - How to identify and map countries NOT included in data file?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a data file of countries that I am mapping with Tableau.  How could I go about obtaining the names and mapping the countries that are NOT mapped from my data file?

Thanks!
Brian

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a more clever way, but you could create a flat file list of all countries, map them, and then a use a filter to exclude on the country property of your dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the bottom right of the map for an indicator warning you about missing location info.

If you click it, you will get several options about how to handle the exceptions. One of the choices leads to an edit panel where you see the problem values and associate them with the right countries.

It would be nice if you could export data from the edit panel. Note there is a checkbox to hide all the values with matching geocoding so that you can focus on the problem data.